# Get Alfresco content from web application

Tags: java, rest, repository, alfresco

Until today I used RESTFul Api to extract content from Alfresco repository so, with an Alfresco Web Script I was able to get the right contented I need. Until today. Now, I need to extract translated content from Alfresco but it seems that Alfresco Javascript API doesn't support the multilingual translation of a content. Do you know it there is another way to get Alfresco content from my web application?

I tried using Alfresco Web Service API for Java with:

```
WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress(alfresco_webservicefactory);
AuthenticationUtils.startSession(getAlfrescoLogin(session), getAlfrescoPassword(session));
```

but I get this exception:

```
05:41:25,576 ERROR ApplicationProperty [72]  - Can not initiate session with Alfresco server.
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getEngineConfiguration(Service.java:813)
```

it seems it's not possible to open a connection from my Tomcat to Alfresco because trying from a simple Java main class it works (but really slow and not applicable to a web application)

Any suggestion?

Comment: FYI: the WS API has been [deprecated](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Content_Management_Web_Services) in favor of the CMIS SOAP binding

Comment: Ah, thanks @skuro. I was reading this https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/cmis-resources-tutorials-and-examples-03212012-1456 Have you experienced any problem using CMIS SOAP from Tomcat to Alfresco?

Comment: Also CMIS not support multilingual. How can I get multilingual content???

Comment: is developing a Java backed web script an option for you?

Comment: yeah, if it works, I can consider it

Comment: Re: multilingual, yuo have to declare the model as such ie: &lt;type>d:mltext&lt;/type>. But this doesn't look like ml issue, maybe you can edit your title to match it?